# Split LPSTR and add up values as a long

Tags: c++, lpstr

I am trying to take an LPSTR in C++ such as "12,30,57" and split it and then add up all of the numbers (they are all non-decimal) that are returned from the split operation into a resulting long value.

This is not homework I can assure you.  It's for an extension I am writing which requires that I code procedural stuff in C++ since the main dev environment does not support functions.  I am a Java/C# developer so this is all a mystery.  NOTE: This is pure C++ and not C++.NET.  I will eventually have to write a version in Objective-C as well (oh joy) so as much ANSI-C++ compliant as possible the better off I will be.

**ANSWER**:

I just wanted to thank everyone for your help and share my code with you which works brilliantly.  This is quite a stretch for me as I'm not really a C++ guy.  But thanks everyone.

```
// Get
long theparam = GetSomeLPSTR(); // e.g. pointer to "1,2,3,4,5,6"

// Set
char *temp = (LPSTR)theparam;
char *temp2 = (LPSTR)malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
strcpy(temp2,temp);

long result = 0;
char * pch;

// Split
pch = strtok(temp2,",");

// Iterate
while (pch != NULL)
{
    // Add to result
    result += atoi(pch);

    // Do it again
    pch = strtok (NULL,",");
}

// Return
return result;
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have access to the standard functions such as `strtok` and the like?

Comment: It's more than promising.  I actually got it to work, but I don't know how to convert an LPSTR to a char[].

Comment: `LPSTR` is the same as `char *`, which is semantically the same as `char []` from the actual programs point of view.

Comment: LPSTR means char* (in a non-Unicode build, presuming you aren't compiling for a 16 bit processor) and char[] is identical to char*.

Comment: Great.  Last problem: How do I copy the contents of one LPSTR into another in an assignment fashion?  E.g. long pointer = GetSomeLPSTR(); LPSTR temp = <<Contents of pointer's LPSTR, but not a pointer to the variable pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get
long theparam = GetSomeLPSTR(); // e.g. pointer to "1,2,3,4,5,6"

// Set
char *temp = (LPSTR)theparam;
char *temp2 = (LPSTR)malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
strcpy(temp2,temp);

long result = 0;
char * pch;

// Split
pch = strtok(temp2,",");

// Iterate
while (pch != NULL)
{
    // Add to result
    result += atoi(pch);

    // Do it again
    pch = strtok (NULL,",");
}

// Return
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

one simple way (there are many, some more or less efficient):

```
LPSTR urcstring = "12,30,57";
std::stringstream ss(urcstring);
long n,m,p; 
char comma;

ss >> n;
ss >> comma;
ss >> m;
ss >> comma;
ss >> p;

std::cout << "sum: " << ( n + m +p ) << std::endl;
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't really know how many #s I will have.  It will vary thus the concept of splitting.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world where you have boost available you could do this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
typedef char* LPSTR;

int total(LPSTR input)
{
    std::vector<std::string> parts;
    std::string inputString(input);
    boost::split(parts, inputString, boost::algorithm::is_any_of(","));
    int total = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < parts.size() ; ++i)
        total += boost::lexical_cast<int>(parts[i]);

    return total;
}
```

The same code will work in Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you need to convert the substrings to `long` anyway, the
simplest solution is probably something like:

```
std::vector<long> results;
std::istringstream source(originalString);
long value;
while ( source >> value ) {
    results.push_back( value );
    char sep;
    source >> sep;
    if ( sep != ',' ) {
        source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
    }
}
if ( ! source.eof() ) {
    //  Format error in input...
}
```